# Reload View when removeFromSuperview in iphoneSDK

Tags: objective-c, ios4

in the main view i call the ViewB like this

```
viewB=[[ViewB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewB" bundle:nil]
[self.View addSubview:viewB];
```

in viewB i call ViewC like this

```
viewC=[[ViewC alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewC" bundle:nil]
[self.View addSubview:viewC];
```

i close ViewC like this to return to viewB

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

When i close ViewC i want to run `- (void)viewDidLoad` in ViewB i mean i want to reload the ViewB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call viewDidLoad directly. If you need some loading functionality that is called several times them create a method and do it there:

```
-(void) reloadData;
```

First time you call it in viewDidLoad. The next time do it when you remove your ViewC. It would be a good idea not to call [self.view removeFromSuperview]; in ViewC. Add method to ViewB:

```
-(void) dismissViewC {
    [viewC removeFromSuperview];
    [self reloadData];
}
```

and call it from ViewC.

However if you're using view controller you can reload your data in

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated;
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot Max , thats what im looking for.